# Get all records from mysql Database

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been trying to do output all of the data from the table but when I do it, it outputs only the first one. I want it to output in my flash application using amfphp. But it only outputs the first line :

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM chatStorage";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $able = true;

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                return $row["user"].": ".$row["chatText"];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: give `echo` instead of `return`

Comment: I'm using it in a function

Comment: then assign it to array and then return it

Comment: it returns [object Object] though

Comment: the less we know, the more time it takes for a full solution; post your full code

Comment: `public function` implies the use of a class; it could be failing you there. `return` makes the first iteration stop. This also sounds like out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

You need to display all values , use print or echo :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM chatStorage";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$able = true;

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // output data of each row

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    print $row["user"].": ".$row["chatText"].PHP_EOL;

  }
}
```

Or if you want to return an array indexed :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM chatStorage";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$able = true;
$myarray = array();

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // output data of each row

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $myarray[$row["user"]][] = $row["chatText"];

  }
}
return $myarray;
```

Comment: In my flash application it returns [object Object] afterwards if i use your edit :P

Comment: flash application ? you have to change it to iterate on [object Object] ;)